# Using Clang-Tidy to gate check in for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clang, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use Clang-Tidy to automatically gate check-ins/builds on Visual Studios.
I know that in **cmake** there is a variable "*CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY*", but setting it to my tidy executable with the proper checks doesn't seem to do anything when building the project.
Also, I am unable to easily generate a *compile_commands.json* for Clang to use. Using CMAKE to generate it messes up individual dependencies, and the only way to generate it through Visual Studios seems to be non automated methods such as Extensions.
I am running the latest version of Clang, Cmake 3.11.3, and Visual Studios 2017.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Did you solve it? CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY works fine on linux.